# Cordova build fails if I set 'type: modules' in package.json. How do I resolve this, yet still carry out unit testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, cordova, es6-modules

I've built a simple app for Android, using the [Cordova framework](https://cordova.apache.org/).  I have now now implemented a simple unit test (using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape)), which runs in Node.  Since the files I'm testing use ES6 modules, in order to run the tests in Node, I had to add `"type": "module",` to my `package.json` file.  But when I did that, my app would no longer build--the Cordova build command fails with the output below.  What is the proper way to resolve this issue?

- Is it possible to programmatically set `"type": "module",`?  If so, I can perhaps set it only when unit tests are running.
- Or is some part of my method flawed in this case? That is certainly a possibility.  Maybe if I test in the browser (rather than in Node), this issue will be avoided?

Thanks.

---

**Build Output**

```
$ cordova build android
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\snarl\my-project\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\snarl\my-project\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js from C:\Users\snarl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename Api.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\snarl\my-project\package.json.

Unhandled error. ('The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else gets stuck on this, here is the solution I used (more of a workaround I guess).  I bundled all files needed for unit testing into one single JS file--`bundle-test.js`--using Browserify (with a Babelify transform).  Then I ran *that* file from the Node command line:  `node test-bundle.js`.  My unit tests ran without issue, and I didn't have to set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.